# Borg prune deletes new archive

Tags: backup

I use BorgBackup for my backups. Here is what i have when i list my archives :

> borg list borg@[SERVER_IP]:/home/backups/$(hostname)
>
> > jenkins_data_2018-06-16              Sat, 2018-06-16 09:28:08
> >
> > redmine_data_2018-06-16              Sat, 2018-06-16 09:31:38

Now, i would like to add the command "borg prune" and check what it could delete :

> borg prune -v --list --dry-run borg@[SERVER_IP]:/home/backups/$(hostname) --keep-daily=7 --keep-weekly=4 --keep-monthly=3
>
> > Keeping archive: redmine_db_2018-06-16                Sat, 2018-06-16 09:31:38
> >
> > Would prune:     jenkins_data_2018-06-16              Sat, 2018-06-16 09:28:08

So, Borg would prune an archive which has been created today.

Do you know why please ?

Answer (score 4):

You told borg prune to keep the latest backup for 7 days.
As the redmine backup is newer (later) than the other one, it keeps that for that day and deletes the other one.

Of course this is not what you wanted as the 2 backups are not for the same input data. But for borg to be able to "see" that, you need to:

```
borg prune --prefix redmine_db_ ...
borg prune --prefix jenkins_data_ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The official **borg prune** manual page (https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/prune.html) dictates:

> If a prefix is set with -P, then only archives that start with the
>   prefix are considered for deletion and only those archives count
>   towards the totals specified by the rules. Otherwise, all archives in
>   the repository are candidates for deletion! There is no automatic
>   distinction between archives representing different contents. These
>   need to be distinguished by specifying matching prefixes.

So, it will consider ALL backups in that repository as the same backupset and so all of them are prunable. You need to specify which backup set to prune with the --prefix argument, and with all the optional arguments you want (-d, -w, -m, etc) so that those arguments are applied only to the backup sets matching your prefix.